# Adding object to array onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var householdData = [];

function householdMember(age, rel, smoker) {
  this.age = age;
  this.rel = rel;
  this.smoker = smoker;
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addHouseholdMember);
  
function addHouseholdMember() {

      var selectedAge = "EaxampleData;
      var selectedRel = "ExampleData";
      var selectedText = "ExampleData";
      var selectedSmoker = "ExampleData";
  
      var currentHouseholdMember = new householdMember(selectedAge, selectedText, selectedSmoker);
      console.log(currentHouseholdMember);
      return householdData.push(currentHouseholdMember);
  
};
```

I am trying to push the object that I am creating into an array. I can console.log the object when the button is clicked, but not return anything out of the click function, I know I missing something basic, but couldn't find out what.

Comment: The return value from a listener doesn't matter (in this situation), what exactly are you trying to do with that `return`? Also note that `push` returns the *new length* of the array.

Comment: Why do you want to return a global variable?

Comment: You can't "push" an object into an array. You can only create a reference to that object in the array. When the function is termonated, also all variables and objects defined in that scope are destroyed. So you end up with a reference to a deleted object.

Comment: I'm trying to return it because I want to build up an array of objects by clicking the button a few times and have it add a new object to the array each time.

Comment: @JohnBull You need not return global variables, because you can directly access them from anywhere. For eg : Immediately after your function call or whenever the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to push the object that I am creating into an array.

It is being pushed, just confirmed your code works

> I can console.log the object when the button is clicked, but not
>   return anything out of the click function

You are passing to console log just the newly created object, to see the array updated try printing the updated array in a console.log like this working example:

```js
var householdData = [];

function householdMember(age, rel, smoker) {
  this.age = age;
  this.rel = rel;
  this.smoker = smoker;
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", addHouseholdMember);

function addHouseholdMember() {
      var selectedAge = "28";
      var selectedRel = "25";
      var selectedText = "22";
      var selectedSmoker = "21";
      var currentHouseholdMember = new householdMember(selectedAge, selectedText, selectedSmoker);
      console.log(currentHouseholdMember);
      console.log(householdData);
      return householdData.push(currentHouseholdMember);
     
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button">CLICK</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Also realize there is a semicolon missing here in your code

```
var selectedAge = "EaxampleData <--;
```

Your logic of passing a callback to click event, then creating new object passing parameters to householdMember function using the new operator to instantiate an object, then pushing new object to array is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your selectedAge data (closing quote) and return the new value, not the result of the push.

```
function addHouseholdMember() {

  var selectedAge = "EaxampleData";
  var selectedRel = "ExampleData";
  var selectedText = "ExampleData";
  var selectedSmoker = "ExampleData";

  var currentHouseholdMember = new householdMember(selectedAge, selectedText, selectedSmoker);
  console.log(currentHouseholdMember);
  householdData.push(currentHouseholdMember);
  return currentHouseholdMember;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Unterminated string constant here , 
 var selectedAge = "EaxampleData;

insert the closing bracket and try again

```js
  var householdData = [];
var addBtn = document.querySelector('.addBtn');
function householdMember(age, rel, smoker) {
  this.age = age;
  this.rel = rel;
  this.smoker = smoker;
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addHouseholdMember);

function addHouseholdMember() {
      var selectedAge = "EaxampleData";
      var selectedRel = "ExampleData";
      var selectedText = "ExampleData";
      var selectedSmoker = "ExampleData";

      var currentHouseholdMember = new householdMember(selectedAge, selectedText, selectedSmoker);
  householdData.push(currentHouseholdMember);
console.log(householdData);
};
```

```html
<a class = 'addBtn'>add</a>
```

here is the working example  https://codepen.io/kamindu/pen/PdwagP?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, to respond. I oopsed that but it's just meant to be example data, in the real code I am working with I am pulling data from a form, and all that is working. But I could see the confusion that typo caused. Learning moment.

Answer (score 0):

Shift the responsibility of pushing data to the `householdMember` by creating another function

Instead of loging the value you can also return it

```js
var addBtn = document.getElementById('btn')
var householdData = [];

function householdMember(age, rel, smoker) {
  this.age = age;
  this.rel = rel;
  this.smoker = smoker;
  this.addVal = function() {
    householdData.push({
      age: this.age,
      rel: this.rel,
      smoker: this.smoker
    })
    return householdData;
  }
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addHouseholdMember);

function addHouseholdMember() {

  var selectedAge = "EaxampleData";
  var selectedRel = "ExampleData";
  var selectedText = "ExampleData";
  var selectedSmoker = "ExampleData";

  var currentHouseholdMember = new householdMember(selectedAge, selectedText, selectedSmoker);
  console.log(currentHouseholdMember.addVal())
};
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are returning the return value of JavaScript `push`function. This returns the **length** of the array. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

What you need to do is first add object to array and **then** return the array.

```
householdData.push(currentHouseholdMember);
return householdData;
```